# json object in javascript to get only the value where value is

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have this objects

```
{"event":"auth success"}
{"event":"status","args":["running"]}
{"event":"console output","args":["openjdk version \"11.0.10\" 2021-01-19"]}
{"event":"console output","args":["OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.10+9)"]}
{"event":"console output","args":["OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.10+9, mixed mode, sharing)"]}
```

I am use this in javascript

```
    var JSONObject = JSON.parse(event.data);
    var theDiv = document.getElementById("cli");
    theDiv.innerHTML += "<div>"+JSONObject["args"]+"</div>";
```

and the outcome is this

```
undefined
running
openjdk version "11.0.10" 2021-01-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.10+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.10+9, mixed mode, sharing)
```

How can i get only the value of args where event = "console output"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are getting the objects one by one in your event stream, you can do this:

```js
var json = `{"event":"console output","args":["OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.10+9)"]}`;

var JSONObject = JSON.parse(json);
var theDiv = document.getElementById("cli");
if(JSONObject.event === "console output") {
  theDiv.innerHTML += "<div>" + JSONObject["args"] + "</div>";
}
```

```html
<div id="cli"></div>
```

On the other hand, if you are getting the objects in the exact format you've posted (which would be invalid JSON), then you need to split them by the newline character, then parse each object separately:

```
var JSONObjects = json.split("\n").map(line => JSON.parse(line));
console.log(JSONObjects);
JSONObjects.forEach(obj => {
  var theDiv = document.getElementById("cli");
  if (obj.event === "console output") {
    theDiv.innerHTML += "<div>" + JSONObject["args"] + "</div>";
  }
});
```

Comment: Nice! this is wokring

Comment: Glad to help! You may accept this answer by clicking on the "tick" button if it works for you.

Comment: I have 1 more question the value of the args is this `["\u003e\u001b[2K\r[18:14:46] [Server thread/INFO]: Unknown command. Type \"help\" for help.\u001b[m"]` how do i remove \u003e\u001b[2K\r and the \u001b[m"]?

Comment: Use `yourString.replaceAll(str, "")` where str is the string you want to remove.

Comment: can you give me an example? i use this but it is not working `stringified = event.data.replaceAll("\u003e\u001b[2K\r", "");`

Comment: It does work. Try this in your console: `"\u003e\u001b[2K\rabc".replaceAll("\u003e\u001b[2K\r", "");`. It outputs abc.

Comment: i dont get it? `event.data = event.data.replaceall("\u003e\u001b[2K\rabc".replaceAll("\u003e\u001b[2K\r", "");`

Comment: `'["\u003e\u001b[2K\r[18:14:46] [Server thread/INFO]: Unknown command. Type \"help\" for help.\u001b[m"]'.replaceAll("\u003e\u001b[2K\r", "").replaceAll('\u001b[m"]', "")
`

Comment: Yes i read it but how do i place it in this `event.data = event.data.replace('', '');`

Comment: Replace the string `["\u003e\u001b...` by `event.data`. You may need to store it in another variable rather than in `event.data` itself.

Comment: i dont get is.. i have this `var theDiv = document.getElementById("cli");
  var JSONObject = JSON.parse(event.data);
  if(JSONObject.event === "console output") {
   theDiv.innerHTML += "<div>" + JSONObject["args"] + "</div>";
  }` where do i add the replace for \u003e\u001b[2K\r

Comment: After `JSONObject["args"]`.

Comment: This is still not wroking? i use the replace after the `JSONObject["args"]`

Answer (score 0):

```
socket.onmessage = function (event) {
            var theDiv = document.getElementById("cli");
            var getCli = event.data.replaceAll("\u003e\u001b[2K\r", "");
            var JSONObject = JSON.parse(getCli);
            if(JSONObject.event === "console output") {
                theDiv.innerHTML += "<div>" + getCli + "</div>";
                
            }
        };
```

output

```
{"event":"console output","args":["\u003e\u001b[2K\r[16:11:16] [Server thread/INFO]: [Server] hoi"]}
```

Why is it not replacing?